# How to send a large hex data file on COM port

Tags: open-source, serial-port, ascii

I can't find any software that will send a file as hex values (All of them treat individual characters as ASCII). I have tried Eltima and Realterm. Converting hex to ascii is also an issue as there are many continuous `0x00` values which translate to null in ascii and won't be reflected/missed out. Is there any software that can help with this? If not, any workaround?

Comment: Does it work if you ZIP the files?

Comment: The mentioned softwares only take txt as input.